# Removing Moen Kitchen Faucet

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to remove a Moen kitchen faucet. It is a single-lever faucet with a separate spray hose.

I disconnected all the supply lines and spray hose. But now I'm having trouble removing the faucet body. There is a bracket underneath the sink, and a nut holding the faucet in place. However, even though I loosened the nut, the faucet still won't come off. There is a gap in the threads on the bolt that seems to prevent the bolt from being removed entirely. Hopefully this all makes sense when you see the picture.

What do I need to do to remove the faucet?[image: Closeup of bracket, bolt, and nut]

Comment: is that hex slot in the end of the threaded rod? ... the section looks like and extension, or a break-off-to-desired-length rod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That nut needs to come all the way off. There may be yet another nut below (above?) it which needs to also come off. The hold-down plate will then slide down and off, allowing faucet removal from the top.

Liberal amounts of spray penetrant will help immensely, and some force may be needed (strike with a long-handled tool) to bust that plate free from its position.

Comment: Thank you!  So I can still remove the nut(s) even with that big gap in the threads?  I haven't tried putting a lot of force on it because I was afraid the nut(s) might get stuck.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy Fix-it!  I was able to get the nut off.